# How can I create a value type with validated construction?

Tags: c#

I want to define a type representing a simplified can bus frame in C#. My intent is to create a type which is both immutable and can be compared by the value of the fields. I also want to guarantee that the data property cannot have a length greater than 8 (a restriction of the can bus protocol). Here's my attempt at defining it as a `record`:

```
record CanFrame
{
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public byte[] Data { get; init; }

    public CanFrame(int id, byte[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length > 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        Id = id;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

This accomplishes the validation of the length of the data array, but it allows me to edit the values of the data array for anyone holding a reference to the object. I believe I can solve that problem by changing the `record` definition to `readonly record struct`, but now someone can create a `CanFrame` with the parameterless constructor. Am I missing something? Should I not worry about the parameterless constructor? Because besides that, the `readonly record struct` seems to be the right way to define this type.

**Edit:**

So I tried the `readonly record struct`, but I didn't like how I couldn't prevent the creation of invalid objects without what seemed like complicated code to me. Here's another attempt at the `record` approach:

```
record CanFrame
{
    private readonly int id;
    private readonly byte[] data;

    public CanFrame(int id, byte[] data)
    {
        if (data is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        if (data.Length > 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(data));

        Id = id;
        this.data = data.ToArray();
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get => id;
        init => id = value;
    }

    public byte[] Data
    {
        get => data.ToArray();
        init
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Data));
            if (value.Length > 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Data));
            data = value.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I think this prevents mutation of the byte array from any caller, but I'm not a fan of the duplication of code in the init setters and the constructor, but if I tried to make a constructor like this:

```
public CanFrame(int id, byte[] data)
{
    Id = id;
    Data = data;
}
```

I get this `CS8618` warning: "Non-nullable field 'data' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable."

Which is annoying because to me, data is guaranteed to be not null when exiting the constructor. I actually don't need to be able to init properties with the `with` expressions for this type, but I have a similar type that this would be useful with.

Comment: How about a [readonly array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.asreadonly?view=net-8.0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using struct, readonly or not, will not resolve the issue in general. Immutability in C# is shallow. As long as you expose array on public surface, it can be modified.

What you could do instead, as suggested in comments, is to use record class and expose the Data property as immutable type, e.g. `IReadOnlyList<byte>`:

```cs
public record CanFrame
{
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public IReadOnlyList<byte> Data { get; init; }

    public CanFrame(int id, byte[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length > 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        Id = id;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Now the contents of the array cannot be changed so easily. However, this still allows usage such as

```cs
var canFrame = new CanFrame(4, Array.Empty<byte>() { Data = new byte[10] };
```

You can avoid this by setting the properties as get-only:

```cs
public record CanFrame
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public IReadOnlyList<byte> Data { get; }

    public CanFrame(int id, byte[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length > 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        Id = id;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

This is what `readonly` does for `record struct` under the hood. Except this does not introduce value type semantics and the associated default parameterless constructor.

It is not very practical in case of primary constructors but for the case where you define the properties explicitly alongside the constructor, there is no downside of using this approach if you want an immutable data type.

Note that there are still two ways to mutate this type.

- Downcast the `IReadOnlyList<T>` to array, this can be avoided by using `AsReadonly`. The cost is duplicating the array.
- Mutate the array passed to your type in constructor from outside. This can be solved by defensive copy, potentially the same way as above.

In practice, I have not seen many cases where someone wanted to shoot themselves in the foot like that so I would personally not do it - duplicating the array has a perf cost. So unless you're writing a library, it might be fine to ignore those scenarios.

In the end, nothing is really immutable if you try hard enough. So the question is mostly about where do you want to draw the line for your project.

Comment: I think you're correct and I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thank you. May I suggest to un-delete your answer? I think it gives different perspective which may be of value as well. My approach does not support `with` expressions, I think.

Comment: Your approach doesn't support `with` because in order to support `with` the properties must also be settable (either by adding `set` or `init` which is more appropriate in this case) - but this can easily be fixed by adding `init` with an explicit backing field and moving the validation to `init`. I don't think there's much value in undeleting my answer

Comment: Instead of `IReadOnlyList<byte>`, I'd use `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` for something that has roughly the same semantics as a byte array (meaning you can get a span on it), but is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider representing the data somewhat differently:

- Rather than exposing a `Data` property, expose an indexer allowing by-index byte access; you can expose a `CopyTo(Span<byte>)` method as well if that's required. (You could *potentially* expose a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` if you really wanted to.)
- Internally, keep a `ulong` with all the data (which should be fine as you've got a maximum of 8 bytes) and separate `Length` property

So something like:

```cs
public struct CanFrame
{
    private readonly ulong data;

    public int Id { get; }
    public int Length { get; }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get { /* implementation */ }
    }
    public void CopyTo(Span<byte> buffer)
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    public CanFrame(int id, byte[] data)
    {
        // Length validation and conversion of the byte array
        // into a ulong via shifting
    }

    // Potentially other constructors, maybe accepting a ReadOnlySpan<byte>
    // or even a ulong and length
}
```

This will not only be fully immutable, but will make `new CanFrame()` represent a reasonable value - a 0-length frame with ID 0. Additionally, it'll be efficient in memory as it doesn't need a separate array object to be stored.

If you *do* want to expose a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` property, you might want to go back to storing the data as an array and returning the result of `AsSpan()` - but you could then cope with the array reference being null (and returning a suitable empty span) because it wouldn't be an autoimplemented property. You'd still need to create a new copy of the data to store though, to avoid callers mutating the array they pass into the constructor.